# How to migrate chanages of target framework from source/local to already deplyed ASP.NET webapplication

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications

I have ASP.NET Web Application that is deployed on production already. I had to change the target framework of the project from 4.5.2 to 4.7.2 on my local/source and push the changes to developement to get tested.

The problem I am facing is when I changed the target framework of the project the packages did not 'handle' it very well and I had to uninstall and reinstall them with  `update-package -reinstall -ignoreDependencies`

Everything works as normal afterwards but I will need to commit 99+ changes. **I am not sure how to handle this migration between the enviroments.** So far all of the changes made in the C# code requred only bulding and exchanging the dll file(copying the one from local to development and replacing it) or direct replacement/add to a new javascript/cshtml file.

Comment: Well that depends on how you initially deployed your site and how you want to do deployment going forward. Do you use Azure DevOps pipelines? Or GitHub Actions? A Jenkins build server? Or do you publish directly from Visual Studio? And if you're not doing one of those methods - why not? Automated publishing is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I manage to solve the problem is:
After changing the target framework I had to remap the packages as mentioned above which caused a lot of changed in my source. All I did was to build the new 'version' of the project and get the whole bin folder and replace it with the one of the deplyed project in the server side, also I had to compare the changes in the config files.